# CSS menu needs to disappear with a click elsewhere

Tags: html, css, checkbox, menu

I made a menu that appears when clicking a hamburger button with CSS and a checkbox. It works nicely so far. But now I want it to disappear when clicking elsewhere on the page, not only when clicking on the hamburger button again. How do I do that, please?

HTML:

```
<div class="navigatie"> 
  <input class="nav-toggle" id="nav-toggle" type="checkbox">
  <nav>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="werkwijze.html">Werkwijze</a></li>
          <li><a href="overons.html">Over ons</a></li>
          <li><a href="faq.html">Faq</a></li>
          <li><a href="accreditatie.html">Accreditatie</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
  <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
    <span><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}
nav { 
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 30%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 40%;
  transform: scale(1,0);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
}
nav a {
  color: #65A624;
  font-size: 1rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-in;
  display: block;
}
nav a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
nav a.active {
  background-color: #65A624;
  color: white;
}
.nav-toggle:checked ~ nav {
  transform: scale(1,1);
}
.nav-toggle:checked ~ nav a {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
}
```

Greetings,

Sandra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS Solution**

If you want it purely CSS you can do the example below, I've edited a few things because your code missed some CSS and HTML to make it reproducible correctly. But the point should be clear. ;)

A overlay appears after opening, you can close the menu by clicking anywhere in the overlay (darker background)

**Advice: use JavaScript**

I would recommend however to make it easier and use JavaScript if that is a option.

```css
.nav-toggle-label {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  background-color: #0F0;
}

.nav-toggle {
  width: 0.1rem;
  height: 0.1rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 30%;
  z-index: 110;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  transform: scale(1, 0);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
}

nav a {
  color: #65A624;
  font-size: 1rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-in;
  display: block;
}

nav a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

nav a.active {
  background-color: #65A624;
  color: white;
}

.nav-toggle:checked~.navigatie nav {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}

.nav-toggle:checked ~ .navigatie a {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.nav-toggle-close {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
}

.nav-toggle:checked ~ .nav-toggle-close {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input class="nav-toggle" id="nav-toggle" type="checkbox">
<label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-close"></label>
<div class="navigatie">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="werkwijze.html">Werkwijze</a></li>
      <li><a href="overons.html">Over ons</a></li>
      <li><a href="faq.html">Faq</a></li>
      <li><a href="accreditatie.html">Accreditatie</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
    <span><i class="fas fa-bars">Menu</i></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I incorporated it and it works.
The problem now is that the overlay only covers the screen width and height, not the whole page. So if i scroll down and then hit the menu button, there's no overlay on the bottom part of the page

Comment: I solved it by setting the height to 500%.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function (event) {
        var clickover = $(event.target);
        var _opened = $(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("navbar-collapse in");
        if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {
            $("button.navbar-toggle").click();
        }
    });
});
```

Check out this jsfiddle sample.
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5718/